# Solving $\sin(6x) + \sin(4x) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a test in a week and this will probably be one of the tasks. So an explanation would also come in handy.

They really need to do something about the questions, though. I need to type 1000 things but all I want is a solution and an explanation. I really don't know how to put that in a 100-word essay...

Comment: Use $\sin (6x)=\sin (4x+2x)$ and $\sin (4x)=\sin {2x+2x}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3225815/edit) the question. [This post](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sin6x+\sin4x=2\sin5x\cos x$$

So, $\sin 5x=0$ or $\cos x=0$

Another way:

\begin{align*}
\sin6x&=-\sin 4x\\
\sin6x&=\sin (\pi+4x)\\
6x&=n\pi+(-1)^n(\pi+4x)\\
x&=\frac{[n+(-1)^n]\pi}{6-4(-1)^n}
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you give me an additional explanation of the first line? I think you used this formula: $sin(2x) = 2sin(x)cos(x)$, but I don't see how you did it.

Comment: It is the sum-to-product formula: $\sin A+\sin B=2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}$.

Comment: See the comment by Martin Hansen.